# SVG Animation with JS & jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, svg

i have to finish some homework:

a animated bike race that is moving from left screen to right.

What i have done so far:

1. created a input field where you can choose the color
2. a button to generate as many bike's you want with your chosen color.

I don't know how to make lines under the bikes's, and have no idea how to move the bike's from left to right! Sorry i'm new to JS and SVG Animation its really for me to understand.

Here is the link for the code:
https://github.com/alemkahrov/Wifi_Kurs_alem/tree/master/Fahrradrennen

Hope you guys can help me out..

thanks

Comment: We don't want all your code, we want a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a simple linear animation, you could use native `setInterval()` function and change the CSS `left` / `translateX()` property to move the bike right. Then stop the animation with `clearInterval()`, once it reaches destination

If you want easing and more control over the animation, consider using a SVG library like [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.animate). You can even control the fill and other properties of your SVG with Snap.svg

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a `@keyframes` to achieve what you want.

This is just a sample on how to move the bike but feel free to make your own way to make it move.

```
@keyframes move-bike {
    0% {transform:translateX(0px)}
    100% {transform:translateX(1000px)}
}
```

then implement the keyframes in your svg.

```
#ausgabe > svg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;

    animation-name: move-bike;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}
```

I am not sure what line under the bike is what you want to achieve but you can try adding a svg line and add it to your svg.

```
<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="500" y2="0" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5" />
```

Please see the sample code below

```js
$(document).on('click','#btn', function() {
  var color = $('#farbe').val();
  $('body > svg').clone().appendTo('#ausgabe').find('path').css({fill:color});
  $('#ausgabe').append($('body > svg').clone().find('path').css({fill: color}));
   });//onclick
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

 #ausgabe > svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
    
    animation-name: move-bike;
    animation-duration: 10s;
 }
 body > svg {
  display: none;
 }
 

@keyframes move-bike {
    0% {transform:translateX(0px)}
    100% {transform:translateX(1000px)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Color: <input type="text" id="farbe"><button id="btn">Neues Fahrrad</button>

 <div id="ausgabe">
 </div>
 
 



 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="1000px" height="676px" viewBox="0 0 1000 676" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 676" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path fill="#020202" d="M671.121,158.532l-7.54-23.653l50.811-27.64c3.315,0.351,6.658-1.241,8.395-4.329
  c2.301-4.13,0.843-9.33-3.325-11.651l-29.877-16.7c-4.139-2.312-9.349-0.843-11.643,3.296c-2.093,3.751-0.956,8.279,2.351,10.836
  c-2.5,0.748-4.519,2.776-4.983,5.523c-0.663,3.864,1.913,7.55,5.808,8.222l11.254,1.96l-32.813,17.855l-2.443-7.691l-11.574,3.694
  l14.019,43.962L671.121,158.532z M684.619,75.582c2.833,0,5.125,2.302,5.125,5.134s-2.292,5.125-5.125,5.125
  c-2.832,0-5.124-2.292-5.124-5.125C679.495,77.884,681.787,75.582,684.619,75.582z"/>
 <path fill="#020202" d="M219.854,263.297c-93.958,0-170.125,76.178-170.125,170.116c0,93.957,76.168,170.145,170.125,170.145
  s170.125-76.188,170.125-170.145C389.979,339.466,313.811,263.297,219.854,263.297z M219.854,583.694
  c-82.998,0-150.271-67.284-150.271-150.281c0-82.998,67.273-150.261,150.271-150.261s150.271,67.271,150.271,150.261
  C370.125,516.421,302.852,583.694,219.854,583.694z"/>
 <path fill="#020202" d="M780.424,263.297c-93.948,0-170.126,76.178-170.126,170.116c0,93.957,76.178,170.145,170.126,170.145
  c93.947,0,170.125-76.188,170.125-170.145C950.549,339.466,874.371,263.297,780.424,263.297z M780.424,583.694
  c-82.998,0-150.263-67.284-150.263-150.281c0-82.998,67.273-150.261,150.263-150.261c83.007,0,150.281,67.271,150.281,150.261
  C930.713,516.421,863.431,583.694,780.424,583.694z"/>
 <path fill="#020202" d="M235.114,411.987c8.847-12.894,38.562-56.371,65.085-96.534c-3.325-2.264-6.792-4.338-10.306-6.318
  l-63.352,98.894c-2.15-0.568-4.357-0.966-6.688-0.966c-14.569,0-26.371,11.802-26.371,26.361c0,14.567,11.812,26.37,26.371,26.37
  c12.39,0,22.706-8.572,25.538-20.091l117.109,2.69c0.17-2.852,0.436-5.684,0.436-8.571c0-0.199-0.028-0.408-0.028-0.606
  l-116.966-2.689C245.089,422.88,241.063,416.229,235.114,411.987z M219.854,446.41c-7.17,0-12.997-5.798-12.997-12.986
  c0-7.181,5.826-12.978,12.997-12.978s12.996,5.797,12.996,12.978C232.85,440.612,227.024,446.41,219.854,446.41z"/>
 <path fill="#020202" d="M776.181,415.15c-1.609,0-3.146,0.274-4.623,0.662l0.065-0.065c0,0-29.505-44.028-39.48-65.899
  c-4.224-9.245-9.804-26.173-15.23-44.085c-3.847,1.914-7.587,3.988-11.234,6.232c5.313,16.511,10.609,31.828,14.521,40.428
  c9.273,20.357,36.461,59.716,42.646,68.582c-3.041,3.27-4.935,7.616-4.935,12.428c0,10.099,8.183,18.291,18.28,18.291
  c10.097,0,18.281-8.184,18.281-18.291C794.462,423.334,786.269,415.15,776.181,415.15z M776.181,442.431
  c-4.973,0-9.009-4.033-9.009-9.007c0-4.965,4.036-9,9.009-9c4.964,0,9.008,4.035,9.008,9
  C785.188,438.405,781.145,442.431,776.181,442.431z"/>
 <path fill="#020202" d="M544.655,446.74l-38.64-15.81c-3.562-1.449-7.605,0.246-9.073,3.809c-0.75,1.838-0.617,3.799,0.141,5.483
  h-5.01c-0.985-8.098-3.779-15.609-8.25-21.976l194.061-183.652l3.401,10.685l3.931-1.25c1.384,4.888,5.191,18.149,9.994,34.177
  c3.884-2.131,7.928-4.007,11.992-5.854c-4.377-15.583-7.72-28.209-8.867-32.511l3.127-0.994l-26.03-81.682l-20.177,6.432
  l4.235,13.29l-285.955,26.334L349.598,125c15.487-3.23,20.896-10.552,30.586-12.475c16.246-3.211,40.333,2.197,40.333-3.202
  c0-8.715-13.573-18.159-30.558-16.729c-13.839,1.175-27.991,3.495-37.369,3.685c-14.086,0.275-56.248-3.353-56.248-3.353
  c-3.05,0-15.639-1.402-11.206,20.518c0.237,1.136,14.768,10.95,38.003,12.712c3.723,0.284,7.048,0.37,10.173,0.36l24.695,80.468
  c-2.586,0.047-22.611,31.069-24.126,33.447l-4.519,7.057l-20.981,32.755c3.571,2.065,7.161,4.121,10.581,6.432
  c8.487-13.193,15.762-24.836,20.631-33.257c10.761-18.604,21.247-25.661,24.259-27.433l54.835,178.65
  c-14.021,8.555-23.482,23.854-23.482,41.472c0,26.921,21.814,48.727,48.716,48.727c25.671,0,46.481-19.92,48.357-45.127h20.659
  c0.605,0,1.185-0.076,1.725-0.198l24.714,10.098c3.561,1.449,7.616-0.237,9.074-3.8C549.902,452.245,548.197,448.19,544.655,446.74
  z M379.048,221.193l286.162-26.362l7.37,23.132L472.778,407.032c-8.091-5.986-17.998-9.643-28.834-9.643
  c-3.657,0-7.181,0.473-10.601,1.23L379.048,221.193z M443.943,489.148c-23.776,0-43.033-19.276-43.033-43.053
  c0-23.747,19.257-43.005,43.033-43.005c21.749,0,39.548,16.189,42.437,37.132h-30.272c-0.521,0-1.004,0.087-1.479,0.182
  c-2.064-3.855-6.005-6.565-10.685-6.565c-6.783,0-12.276,5.495-12.276,12.277s5.493,12.286,12.276,12.286
  c5.531,0,10.031-3.742,11.565-8.772c0.199,0.011,0.389,0.067,0.598,0.067h30.501C484.75,471.758,466.469,489.148,443.943,489.148z
   M449.987,446.106c0,3.354-2.709,6.043-6.055,6.043c-3.343,0-6.053-2.689-6.053-6.043c0-3.345,2.71-6.045,6.053-6.045
  C447.278,440.063,449.987,442.772,449.987,446.106z M522.697,450.767c-2.614,0-4.708-1.864-5.268-4.318
  c0.104-0.464,0.246-0.891,0.246-1.486c0-0.465-0.123-0.768-0.188-1.156c0.644-2.312,2.682-4.045,5.21-4.045
  c3.03,0,5.494,2.474,5.494,5.504C528.191,448.296,525.738,450.767,522.697,450.767z"/>
</g>

</svg>
```

Hope this helps.